# 'The given key was not present in the dictionary' - but the key exists

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, keynotfoundexception

I am currently developing a MS Dynamics CRM 2013 - Plugin.
When I try to assign a string-value to a key of a field of an entity it gives me the 'keynotfound'-exception.

This leaves me clueless, because I can verify the key is existing. The key I give is also written correctly, and the data types are compatible, too.

Here's some extra info:

- I tried resolving the issue with a server reboot. Nothing.
- Remote Debugging is not an option.
- I swapped "retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i][forField]" with retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i]["new_name"] and everything was working fine (kind of pointing out the obvious here, but "new_name" is not the key I try to access).
- The execution stops @ "if (retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i][forField].ToString() != "" && !overwriteExisting)"

Have you got an idea to help me out?

```
public void GenerateNumberForEntityCollection(string target)
{
    try
    {
        // variables for number generation
        bool overwriteExisting = (bool)preImageEntity["new_overwriteexisting"];
        int suffixstart = (int)preImageEntity["new_suffixstart"];
        string forField= preImageEntity["new_forfield"].ToString();
        string prefix = preImageEntity["new_prefix"].ToString();
        string postfix = preImageEntity["new_postfix"].ToString();
        string separator = preImageEntity["new_separator"].ToString();

        // Build query to get all the entries
        RetrieveMultipleResponse retrieved;
        int PageNumber = 1;
        string PagingCookie = string.Empty;
        int PageSize = 5000;
        string[] Columns = { forField };
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
        {
            EntityName = target,
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(Columns),
            PageInfo = new PagingInfo()
            {
                PageNumber = 1,
                Count = PageSize
            }
        };

        do
        {
            if (PageNumber != 1)
            {
                query.PageInfo.PageNumber = PageNumber;
                query.PageInfo.PagingCookie = PagingCookie;
            }

            RetrieveMultipleRequest retrieve = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
            retrieve.Query = query;
            retrieved = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)service.Execute(retrieve);

            // Now that all entities are retrieved, iterate through them to gen. the numbers
            int i = 0;
            foreach (Entity entity in retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities)
            {
                if (retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i][forField].ToString() != "" && !overwriteExisting)
                {
                    //continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i][forField] = prefix + separator + suffixstart.ToString() + separator + postfix;
                }
                suffixstart++;
                service.Update(retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i]);
                i++;
            }
            if (retrieved.EntityCollection.MoreRecords)
            {
                PageNumber++;
                PagingCookie = retrieved.EntityCollection.PagingCookie;
            }
        } while (retrieved.EntityCollection.MoreRecords);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tracing.Trace("GenerateNumberForEntityCollection: Failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are querying data in Dynamics CRM it is important to know that record fields having `null` values in the database are not included in the `Attributes` collection of the `Entity` instances being returned.

Getting a value from an `Entity`'s `Attribute` with this construct:

```
var value = retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i][forField].ToString();
```

succeeds when attribute `forField` already has a value in the database, but *fails* when its current value is `null`.

Therefore the preferred method to get the attribute values from an entity is `GetAttributeValue<T>`, like this:

```
var value = retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i].getAttributeValue<string>(forField);
```

This method returns the value when the attribute exists in the attribute collection, otherwise it returns `null`.

Answer (score 3):

How did you verify that the key exists?

If the data in a **field is null**, the Entity instance **will not contain that key**, even if you specify it in the query's ColumnSet.

This will return you a boolean, indicating if the key exists in the Entity. You can do this control before attempting to read the attribute.

```
var attributeExists = retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i].Contains(forField)
```

The control below you've done will result in the exception you're getting if the field is null. Just make sure that the attribute exists before.

```
retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities[i][forField].ToString() != ""
```

<del>Additionally, you'll get a null reference exception if no records were returned from the query. Make you do a null check on retrieved.EntityCollection.Entities.</del>

Comment: I would not advise to check if the attribute collection actually contains a specific member. The preferred method is to use the `GetAttribute<T>` method. Also, the `DataCollection<Entity>` returned by `IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple` (like in `retrieved.EntyCollection.Entities`) is always present, so a `null` check is not needed there either.

Answer (score 1):

> If any of the fields among
>   (new_forfield,new_prefix,new_postfix,new_separator) has null value,
>   that column does not present in the retrieved object and you are trying to get the value of null column **preImageEntity["new_forfield"]** which will throw **keynotfound'-exception** ,
>   so change the code

```
string forField= preImageEntity["new_forfield"].ToString();
string prefix = preImageEntity["new_prefix"].ToString();
string postfix = preImageEntity["new_postfix"].ToString();
string separator = preImageEntity["new_separator"].ToString();
```

**to**

```
string forField = preImageEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_forfield")? preImageEntity["new_forfield"].ToString():"";
string prefix = preImageEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_forfield") ? preImageEntity["new_prefix"].ToString() : "";
string postfix = preImageEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_forfield") ? preImageEntity["new_postfix"].ToString() : "";
string separator = preImageEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_forfield") ? preImageEntity["new_separator"].ToString() : "";
```

> this will check for field, if it exists than will parse the value to
>   string else will assign empty string.